# HTTPContext in a Load Balanced Env

Tags: c#, .net, deployment

How can Items stored in the HttpContext be managed in an NLB deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpContext is per user and per request, so there is no reason to share it between machines. What you need is probably session state in SQL server mode.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

Or save state in cookies, etc. There are more options.